# Excel formula to sum all cells that are in a list of given column numbers?

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, formula

I have data that looks like this

[image: http://screencast.com/t/RN7x6szA60]

```
Bin 0   Bin 1   Bin 2   Bin 3   Bin 4   Bin 5   Bin 6   Bin 7
0.6967  0.6967  0.0503  0.0497  0.0971  0.0526  0.0009  0.0013
```

And I have a list of bins to sum, for example I want to sum bins 2,5 and 7. How would I write formula to sum all the cells for those bins numbers? I tried something like {=SUM(OFFSET(A2,,{2,5,7}))} but I don't think I'm using array formulas correctly because it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use SUMIFS():

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(2:2,1:1,{"Bin 2","Bin 5","Bin 7"}))
```

[image]

If you want to just list the bin numbers in a range then you could use this instead:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(2:2,1:1,"Bin " & I5:I7))
```

This will need to be entered as an array formula, with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done properly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that is sort of what I'm looking for, but I have the bins as just a list of numbers. ie. "2,5,7" and there are actually hundreds of bins so typing them in manually won't work. That's why I was trying to do it using OFFSET. Is there a way to modify your formula to accommodate that problem? I could always just use another script to reformat the list if not

Comment: How is your list stored? @Esoremada

Comment: And do the column headers all start with `Bin `?

Comment: It's from another Excel file in a column as well as in raw text in a row with values separated by commas. Yes all the headers are of the format Bin #

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of SUM and VLOOKUP to achieve this simply you pass the list of cell numbers as the index of VLOOKUP (yes it support list as index !!) you could try the following:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(A2, A2:M2, {2, 5, 7}, false))

{2, 5, 7}      : is the list of indexes you specify to be summed
first argument : must be the first element in the range 
second argument: is the range to look up into
result         : B2+E2+G2
```

and remember to treat this equation as array equation by surrounding it with curly braces or by pressing ctrl-shift-enter instead of enter